# Why is this method returning without hitting the return statement?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having a baffling issue with this method in my app:

```
    override suspend fun hasLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation: WeatherLocation): Boolean {
        val deviceLocationChanged = try {
            hasDeviceLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation)
        } catch (e: LocationPermissionNotGrantedException) {
            false
        }

        return deviceLocationChanged || hasCustomLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation)
    }
```

It seems to be returning out of the method without actually calling the return statement and I don't know how that's possible or why it's happening.  The function `hasDeviceLocationChanged()` is returning false (which is correct), and it is not catching an exception, but the `hasLocationChanged()` function returns true, without calling the return statement.

I've put breakpoints in the try, the catch, and the return, and only the breakpoint inside the try block is ever hit.

I've never seen this before, and am hoping someone is able to help.  Here is the whole class for reference:

```
const val USE_DEVICE_LOCATION = "USE_DEVICE_LOCATION"
const val CUSTOM_LOCATION = "CUSTOM_LOCATION"

class LocationProviderImpl(
        private val fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient,
        context: Context
) : PreferenceProvider(context), LocationProvider {

    private val appContext = context.applicationContext

    override suspend fun hasLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation: WeatherLocation): Boolean {
        val deviceLocationChanged = try {
            hasDeviceLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation)
        } catch (e: LocationPermissionNotGrantedException) {
            false
        }

        return deviceLocationChanged || hasCustomLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation)
    }

    override suspend fun getLatitude(): Double {
        val lastLocation = getLastDeviceLocation().await() ?: return 0.0

        return lastLocation.latitude
    }

    override suspend fun getLongitude(): Double {
        val lastLocation = getLastDeviceLocation().await() ?: return 0.0

        return lastLocation.longitude
    }

    override suspend fun getPreferrredLocationString(): String {
        if (isUsingDeviceLocation()) {
            try {
                val deviceLocation = getLastDeviceLocation().await()
                        ?: return "${getCustomLocationName()}"
                return "${deviceLocation.latitude}, ${deviceLocation.longitude}"
            } catch (e: LocationPermissionNotGrantedException) {
                return "${getCustomLocationName()}"
            }
        } else {
            return "${getCustomLocationName()}"
        }
    }

    private suspend fun hasDeviceLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation: WeatherLocation): Boolean {
        if (!isUsingDeviceLocation())
            return false

        val deviceLocation = getLastDeviceLocation().await()
                ?: return false

        val comparisonThreshold = 0.03
        return Math.abs(deviceLocation.latitude - lastWeatherLocation.latitude) > comparisonThreshold &&
                Math.abs(deviceLocation.longitude - lastWeatherLocation.longitude) > comparisonThreshold
    }

    private fun hasCustomLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation: WeatherLocation): Boolean {
        val customLocationName = getCustomLocationName()
        return customLocationName != lastWeatherLocation.getLocationString(appContext)
    }

    private fun isUsingDeviceLocation(): Boolean {
        return preferences.getBoolean(USE_DEVICE_LOCATION, true)
    }

    private fun getCustomLocationName(): String? {
        return preferences.getString(CUSTOM_LOCATION, null)
    }


    private fun getLastDeviceLocation(): Deferred<Location?> {
        return if (hasLocationPermission())
            fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.asDeferred()
        else
            throw LocationPermissionNotGrantedException()
    }

    private fun hasLocationPermission(): Boolean {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(appContext,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check what the `hasCustomLocationChanged` method is returning?

Comment: I haven't, because it never hits that line.  That's the whole issue, the line with the return is never called

Answer (score 0):

Ironically enough, this seems to be a bug in Android Studio's debugger.  The functions in the return statement actually were being called, but the debugger wasn't catching that breakpoint for some reason.  I just set a breakpoint in the function the return was calling and found the issue.

Comment: Possibly not, but I don't know how to test for that